# Get thousand separator of numbers in different languages Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In English locale the number looks like this: `111,111,222.00`  so thousand separator is a comma and decimal separator is a point. In e.g. German the same number looks like `111.111.222,00` so thousand and decimal separator are reversed. Is there a way to find a thousand separator based on locale?

I found https://angular.io/api/common/getLocaleNumberFormat `getLocaleNumberFormat()` function in angular, but I couldn't find how to use it as it always return format `en` locale format

Answer (score 7):

Use [getLocaleNumberSymbol()](https://angular.io/api/common/getLocaleNumberSymbol).

`getLocaleNumberSymbol(locale: string, symbol: NumberSymbol): string`

```
import { getLocaleNumberSymbol, NumberSymbol } from '@angular/common';

// returns thousands sepator, comma (,) in this case:
getLocaleNumberSymbol('en-US', NumberSymbol.CurrencyGroup)
// returns decimal separator, dot (.) in this case:
getLocaleNumberSymbol('en-US', NumberSymbol.CurrencyDecimal)
```

You should import your locale data into the `AppModule` if it's different from `en-US`:

```
import '@angular/common/locales/global/en-GB';

@NgModule({...})
export class AppModule {
}
```

List of available locales can be found here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/common/locales

Answer (score 1):

I usually set global locale in my app.module.

**App.Module.ts**

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeHe from '@angular/common/locales/he';

registerLocaleData(localeHe, 'he');

@NgModule({ // ....
```

[Angular I18n docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)

Comment: But it always returns me format ` #,###.00 ` shouldn't it return ` #.###,00` if `de` language is set?

Answer (score 1):

As the Angular documentation says, you have to provide the locale as first argument to the `getLocaleNumberFormat()` function:

> `getLocaleNumberFormat(locale: string, type: NumberFormatStyle): string`
>   
>   **Parameters:**
>   `locale : string` A locale code for the locale format rules to use. 
>   `type : NumberFormatStyle` The type of numeric value to be formatted (such as Decimal or Currency.)

If you provide the correct language string, the formatting should work.

Comment: But it always returns me format ` #,###.00 ` shouldn't it return ` #.###,00` if `de` language is set?

Comment: Yes, the latter format should be used. Do you pass the correct language string (`'de-DE'`) into the function?